# then mistake at function PHP

Tags: php

I can not find the error .. Does not change the color at this function

```
    function foo($string, $color)
{
    echo '<p style="color: '.$color.';">'.$string.'</p>';

}
foo("example", FF00AE);
?>
```

Comment: Whats FF00AE, Its not in quotes and it should be "#FF00AE"

Comment: foo("example", "#FF00AE");

Comment: you should probably quote the color.  Also, don't suppress errors - show them, and ti will tell you if there is something wrong  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: FF00AE technically could be a defined constant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
    function foo($string, $color)
{
    echo '<p style="color: '.$color.';">'.$string.'</p>';

}
foo("example", "#FF00AE");
```

Need to be a string and start with # hexdecimal color symbol also your echo had a wrong chart ; I fixed it

Comment: the `;` you removed belonged to the style-syntax.

Comment: It was making the echo stop and breaking the execution of the echo

Comment: No, it was inside of the (html-) string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I will fix

Comment: It will work either way (with or without the semicolon), and produce valid HTML markup too. Its a separator if you have multiple styling properties.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
`foo("example", FF00AE);`
With:
`foo("example", "#FF00AE");`

FF00AE should be passed as a string and needs to be prefixed with # sign as its a hexadecimal code for color.